# How to convert digital information(e.g.KB,MB,B) units in Scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I tried to unify the digital information unit in Scala.How to use `combineByKey()` to operate on value.

```
val avg = scores.combineByKey(
    (v) => (v, 1),
    (acc: (Float, Int), v) => (acc._1 + v, acc._2 + 1),
    (acc1:(Float, Int), acc2:(Float, Int)) => (acc1._1 + acc2._1, acc1._2 + acc2._2)
)
```

I tried to use this function, but don't know how to separate letters and numbers.

```
e.g.
input:
(text1,3B)
(text1,45KB)
(text2,88MB)
(text2,98KB)
(text3,25B)

output:
(text1,List(3B,46080B))
(text2,List(92274688B,100352B))
(text3,List(25B))
```

Comment: You're using spark?

Comment: Yes. Just two days of study. .

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood your question, but from your example it looks like you are looking for something like this:

```scala
val input = Seq(
  ("text1","3B"),
  ("text1","45KB"),
  ("text2","88MB"),
  ("text2","98KB"),
  ("text3","25B")
)

val grouped = input.groupBy(_._1)
// grouped:Map[String, Seq[(String, String)]] = Map("text3" -> List(("text3", "25B")), "text2" -> List(("text2", "88MB"), ("text2", "98KB")), "text1" -> List(("text1", "3B"), ("text1", "45KB")))

val sizesByText = grouped.mapValues(_.map(_._2))
// sizeByText = Map[String, Seq[String]] = Map("text3" -> List("25B"), "text2" -> List("88MB", "98KB"), "text1" -> List("3B", "45KB"))

val PATTERN = """(\d+)(B|KB|MB)""".r
def byteSize(size: String) = {
   val bytes = size match {
     case PATTERN(amount, "B") => amount.toInt
     case PATTERN(amount, "KB") => (amount.toInt * 1024)
     case PATTERN(amount, "MB") => (amount.toInt * 1024 * 1024)
     case _ => throw new IllegalArgumentException(s"invalid size: $size")
   }
   bytes + "B"
}

val output = sizesByText.mapValues(_.map(byteSize)).toSeq
//output: Seq[(String, Seq[String])] = Vector(("text3", List("25B")), ("text2", List("92274688B", "100352B")), ("text1", List("3B", "46080B")))
```